# Best practices структуры проекта

Tags: java, java-ee, проектирование

Если отвлечься от [юмористичных](https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition) (не без доли *серьёзности*) шаблонов Java-проектов с их "/main/java/com/seriouscompany/business/java/" и т.д., то, всё же, какая структура может считаться минималистичным и не гротескным эталоном, который удобен в разработке, а также может быть без стыда продемонстрирован серьёзным людям?

Comment: чем плоха стандартная maven-овская структура проекта?

Comment: @Nofate ничем не плоха, но всегда есть альтернативы.

Answer (score 7):

1. Заведите себе свой собственный домен ну например kiselevadev.ru - впрочем можно физически не регать домен, но мы же говорим о серьезных людях?
2. Все свои прожекты впишите в пакеты типа: `ru.kiselevadev.myproject`
3. Далее дерево прожекта строим в виде:

/src - исходники

/test - исходники тестов

/lib - либы

/ext - прочие ресурсы: ТЗ, картинки и проч.

/docs - документация

Comment: Использую почти такую же структуру, но всё равно задаюсь вопросами.

Comment: Зря вы вопросами задаётесь.

Структура должна быть либо mave'овская (это почти всегда структура по умолчанию для сборщиков), либо (только если maven'овская не подходит) диктоваться условиями разработки.

Comment: Не одобряю такой maven-центрик подход. В мире есть немало девелоперов не использующих maven и еще больше вообще не знающих что это за зверь. Есть ведь немало альтернативных билдеров.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦
Это может пройти на проектах с небольшим временем поддержке, Но в enterprise разработке (с поддержкой по 10 лет) нужно переходить на maven структуру.

К тому же есть преимущества такой структуры:

1) Почти всегда эта структура по умолчанию для *модных* сборщиков (вроде gradle)

2) Можно совмещать код на разных языках (src/main/java, src/main/groovy, src/test/java, src/test/groovy)

Из этого я делаю вывод, что лучше сразу с maven'а начинать.

Answer (score 3):

Лучше этого еще ничего не придумали:
[Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)