# Пакеты в Java (Package). Как понимать и использовать?

Tags: java, package

Могу ли я использовать пакеты на локальной машине? Потому что как я понял, это возможно только на удленной.

Я хочу так, например.

C:\JavaProj\StackOF\src

Там Main.java

И:

C:\JavaProj\StackOF\classes

Там Classes.java

В Classes.java прописать

`package JavaProj.StackOF.classes;`

А в Main.java

`import JavaProj.StackOF.classes.*;`

Заработает ли это или я в корне чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Заработает или нет - какая разница. Без кода это все равно понять нельзя.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что где-то на удалённой машине находятся "пакеты", и вы хотите их импортировать и использовать в своей программе на своём компьютере?

Comment: Нет, я имею совсем противоположное. Я хочу импортировать на своем компьютере из другой папки проекта.

Comment: Ну так, ещё проще. Вы тот проект, пакеты которого хотите использовать, соберите в jar-файл. Подключите его в classpath (среда разработки легко это делает) того проекта, в котором хотите использовать. И всё, готово.

Comment: У вас неправильные представления о структуре проекта в Java, см. [Best practices структуры проекта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/293309/).  Директория `src` предназначена для исходного кода (`.java` файлов), а директория `classes` -- для скомпилированных `.class` файлов.  Также названия пакетов принято писать строчными буквами.

Comment: classes я написал наугад, это совпало со стандартной структурой. Вместо classes может быть любая другая папка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Папки следующие:

> C:\JavaProj\Variables\src\classnum
>
> C:\JavaProj\Variables\src

Можно добавить в папку

> src

папку

> classnum

и создать там два файла: *Class1.java, Class2.java*. В обоих файлах первой строкой прописать **package classnum;**
В этих классах создать метод

> public static void print() { System.out.println("Name of class"); }

,который выводит в консоль название класса.
В файле *Main.java* (папка src) первой строкой идет **import classnum.*;** В методе main вызываются два метода из пакета classnum, в который входят два класса Class1 и Class2:

> Class1.print();
>
> Class2.print();

Консоль:

> C:\JavaProj\Variables\src>javac Main.java
>
> C:\JavaProj\Variables\src>java Main
>
> Class1
>
> Class2
>
> C:\JavaProj\Variables\src>

Answer (score 2):

Пакеты — механизм языка. Работают они **на любой машине, на которой стоит java.**

Главное, чтобы вы всё правильно сделали:

- Каждый пакет — это папка. Имя пакета отсчитывается от корня проекта (но названия корневой директории в имени пакета нет!). То есть у вас корень проекта диск `C:\`, а имена пакетов — `JavaProj.StackOF.classes` и `JavaProj.StackOF.src`.
- Если `.java`-файл лежит в каком-то пакете, то первая строка (не считая комментариев) должна содержать оператор `package` с названием пакета. То есть в `Main.java` вам **тоже нужно прописать**:

  ```java
  package JavaProj.StackOF.src;
  ```
- Если вы хотите использовать класс из другого пакета (например класс `Classes` из пакета `JavaProj.StackOF.classes` вы хотите как-то использовать в классе `Main` из другого пакета), то вы должны либо импортировать нужный вам класс из другого пакета:

  ```java
  import JavaProj.StackOF.classes.Classes;
  ```

  Либо каждый раз прописывать полный путь от корня проекта, что не очень
  удобно:

  ```java
  JavaProj.StackOF.classes.Classes someObject = new JavaProj.StackOF.classes.Classes();
  ```

Насколько я понял, у вас проблема со вторым пунктом — вы не прописали `package JavaProj.StackOF.src;` в `Main.java`. Если же вы это сделали, и проблема в другом, то пожалуйста, дополните вопрос деталями.

Comment: Main.java:2: error: package JavaProj.Variables.classes does not exist
import JavaProj.Variables.classes.Nothing;
                                 ^
1 error

Comment: @Snake_51 ошибка говорит, что пакета `JavaProj.Variables.classes.Nothing` не существует. См. пункт 1.